# What are the recommended GPUs for Ansys Discovery, and why?

Tags: graphics-cards

Ansys Discovery (2024R1) provides upfront simulation (analysis) for solid design, and "real time" simulation results, but which aspects of a GPU are critical, important, and in which way ?

eg., FP32, FP64, sparse matrix, tensor, memory size, memory bandwidth, pcie generation ?

Subsequently, how to choose or rank GPUs, given what could be done in Ansys Discovery ?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.ansys.com/content/dam/it-solutions/platform-support/graphical-display-graphics-cards-tested-2022-r1.pdf

*Discovery: NVIDIA Discrete graphics card with the latest drivers. Pascal series or newer recommended. At least 4 GB of discrete video memory (8 GB recommended).
OpenGL version 4.6 or above. AMD Radeon Pro cards are also supported, with the exception of the Explore stage, and when running under Discovery Modeling at least 2 GB of discrete video memory is required (4+ GB recommended).*

> which aspects of a GPU are critical, important, and in which way?

that will be an answer you need to ask ANSYS, as it will be based on their proprietaty solver, which they may not divulge in detail.

> what are the recommended gpus for ansys discovery

basically whatever you can afford and what will physically fit.

> how to choose or rank GPUs

https://www.videocardbenchmark.net/high_end_gpus.html

Comment: being commercial software having license costs, you are at least entitled to a decent answer from them if you are already paying them and using the software.  If you are considering using it put have not yet purchased a license (in either case) you need to formally ask them in a professional manner.  And it would also be far better to ask such a question at the ansys forum/community website rather than here.  It's a good question but I seriously doubt you will get your answer here.

Comment: I did not mean ask for a publicly provided answer.  open a support ticket with them under the license you are paying for and ask the question you want a technical answer for.  I'm curious how & why you think *they are wrong* in regards to what the software does and doesn't use or do, when that was fundamentally your question you did not have an answer for to begin with.